# jhipster entity exception in linux(ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: jhipster

Well, I used command "yo jhipster" to generate a monolithic application, use all the default function.

Use "yo jhipster:entity" to generate a new entity, encounter following error:

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Did not provide required argument name!
    at constructor.<anonymous> (/home/yhjhoo/IdeaProjects/jhipster_test/jhipster-microservice/test/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/base.js:383:33)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at constructor.Base.checkRequiredArgs (/home/yhjhoo/IdeaProjects/jhipster_test/jhipster-microservice/test/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/base.js:379:19)
    at constructor.argument (/home/yhjhoo/IdeaProjects/jhipster_test/jhipster-microservice/test/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/base.js:344:8)
    at new constructor (/home/yhjhoo/IdeaProjects/jhipster_test/jhipster-microservice/test/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/entity/index.js:34:14)
    at Environment.instantiate (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:328:10)
    at Environment.create (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:305:15)
    at Environment.run (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:364:24)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/cli.js:140:11
    at Array.forEach (native)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to provide an entity name, the following command works.

```
$ yo jhipster:entity person
```

Comment: And that's why the error says `Did not provide required argument name!` :-)

Comment: But I agree having a stacktrace isn't very pretty, I think that comes from Yeoman and we can't improve it, but I'll have a look